# PyTorch MultiHeadAttention implementation

Tags: pytorch, multihead-attention

In Pytorch's MultiHeadAttention [implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#MultiheadAttention), regarding in_proj_weight, is it true that the first embed_dim elements correspond to the query, the next embed_dim elements correspond to the key, and the final embed_dim elements correspond to the value? Just confirming.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532911/why-is-the-input-size-of-the-multiheadattention-in-pytorch-transformer-module-15/78004965#78004965) is a question asked in the same context, but doesn't answer my specific question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the case.

You can see how `in_proj_weight` is used in the [_in_projection_packed](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4eefe7285a4d105650d02a02ada73ebb782e0b2d/torch/nn/functional.py#L4846) function

```
projection weights for q, k and v, packed into a single tensor. Weights
are packed along dimension 0, in q, k, v order.
```